# How can I change touch animation radius

Tags: flutter, dart

Can I change the radius of button . in my current app I am using Icon button but when I click the button It take a big area I mean the clickable area is too big normalsize button How can I change the radius witouth changing button size
Thanks for your help

Comment: Add your code snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `padding` and `splashRadius`.

```dart
   IconButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            splashRadius: 16,
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.ac_unit_outlined,
            ),
          ),
```

or you can choose `InkWell` like

```dart
     InkWell(
            customBorder: CircleBorder(),
            onTap: () {
              print("tapped");
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
              child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: in case of ```InkWell``` you can use ```customBorder: CircleBorder()``` instead of ```borderRadius```